# ASP.NET Core - 'AccessToken' does not implement interface member 'IEntity.Id'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core-6, I have this models:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IAuditable
{
    Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }
    DateTimeOffset? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    DateTimeOffset? LastModifiedOn { get; set; }
    Guid? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    DateTimeOffset? DeletedOn { get; set; }
    Guid? DeletedBy { get; set; }
}
```

When I tried to implement it here:

```
public class AccessToken : IEntity, IAuditable
{
    public string IssuedBy { get; set; }
    public string Audience { get; set; }
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    public string UserAgent { get; set; }
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string TokenId { get; set; }
    public Guid? ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public Guid LoginId { get; set; }
    public string ClientToken { get; set; }
    public string Claims { get; set; }
}
```

I got this error:

> 'AccessToken' does not implement interface member 'IEntity.Id'

> 'AccessToken' does not implement interface member 'IAuditable.CreatedBy'

> 'AccessToken' does not implement interface member 'IAuditable.CreatedOn'

and so on.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you implement those properties?

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: An interface tells you what the class has to implement, but it does not do it for you. It's a blueprint that you have to follow. Even "simple" properties can have non-trivial implementations, it's up to you to think of how you want to do it (simple or complex).

Comment: [Interface Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface#example-interface)

Comment: As you're using interface you need to implement the properties. You should use class to inherit properties

Answer (score 0):

That's how [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/inheritance) works. In your case, you have an interface and you're trying to implement it, so you need to inherit all the stuff, in C# it's all the methods(if not [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods)) and properties.

So, you need to add all the missing properties(you mentioned them in the body of the post)